# Total newbie unable to install a programme

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I have literally just installed Kubuntu to see what it is all about. I am a total newbie and have tried to install a programme called uGet.

I managed to download it but don't know where to go from there. I have been reading the forums and have tried Discover, but uGet is not available there so have tried a few things in bash, but no luck (please see below). Any help greatly appreciated.

```
nleric@nleric-SATELLITE-L50-C:~$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
[sudo] password for nleric: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

nleric@nleric-SATELLITE-L50-C:~$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package synaptic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate

nleric@nleric-SATELLITE-L50-C:~$ sudo apt-get install uGet
[sudo] password for nleric: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package uGet

nleric@nleric-SATELLITE-L50-C:~$ sudo apt-get install software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 1):

uGet actually has instructions on its [website](http://ugetdm.com/downloads-ubuntu).

You need to run the commands below to add the PPA, then install it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plushuang-tw/uget-stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install uget
```

Just a pointer, I don't think I've ever seen a package name with uppercase letters, so when you install a package through the terminal, use lowercase. I also think package names are case-sensitive, but I'm not sure about that.

If you want the Ubuntu Software Center, you need to run one of the following commands.

If you have Ubuntu 15.10 or lower, run:

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

<sub>As you are getting an error when trying to install this, I'm assuming you have 16.04</sub>

16.04 (and above):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-software packagekit
```

Comment: I thought that in 16.04 just apt is used and not apt-get. Am I wrong?

Comment: @NonStandardModel oh right, that can be used. But `apt-get` still works.

Answer (score 0):

At least Synaptics is part of the universe package as far as I know.

So you need to activate universe:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

I hope this works too on Kubuntu

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses, all went well until  near the end of the installation and then I got this.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 uget : Depends: libappindicator3-1 (>= 0.2.92) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.